# Change text size on label.new (pine-script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I created a label via Pine-Script, but the text is very tiny. Can you please help me to change the text size? Here is my code:

```
label.new(x = bar_index, y=na, yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = color.aqua, text = "1", textcolor = color.aqua, style = label.style_xcross, size =[enter image description here][1] size.auto)
```

"1" is displayed very small

[image]

I tried to use plotshape, the text is normal. But when changing to label.new, it does not works

Answer (score 0):

`label.new()` has an argument called `size` which you should use.

> ***size (series string)*** Label size. Possible values: size.auto,
> size.tiny, size.small, size.normal, size.large, size.huge. Default
> value is size.normal.

## Edit:

```
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, "1", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.aqua, textcolor = color.aqua, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.auto)
    label.new(bar_index[1], high, "1", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.aqua, textcolor = color.aqua, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.tiny)
    label.new(bar_index[2], high, "1", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.aqua, textcolor = color.aqua, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.small)
    label.new(bar_index[3], high, "1", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.aqua, textcolor = color.aqua, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.normal)
    label.new(bar_index[4], high, "1", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.aqua, textcolor = color.aqua, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.large)
    label.new(bar_index[5], high, "1", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.aqua, textcolor = color.aqua, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.huge)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried "size" argument, but it just effect to "xcross" size, the text size is still tiny

Comment: No, it effects both. See my edit.

Comment: But the xcross become very large, I want it look like the plotshape one. Please see my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaaWJ.png
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaaWJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, you just need to adjust the label offset so it plots where you want it.

```
close_up= close > close[1]

plotshape(close_up, 'up', shape.xcross , color=color.green, location =  location.belowbar)
if close_up
    label.new(bar_index, low - 10, text = '1', style = label.style_label_down, color = color.new(color.white,100), size = size.large)
```

[image]